# Java method that updates a single field of a document in mongodb without creating a new document

Tags: java, database, mongodb, nosql, backend

I need to create a java method that updates a single field of a document in mongodb without creating a new document and if the field does not exist to be updated it must be created. I would like an example of how to do this method.

Comment: What research did you do so far?

Comment: dont use `upsert`

Comment: You can refer the [MongoDB Java Driver Documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver/tutorials/perform-write-operations/) - see the Update Existing Documents sub topic. Also, see the MongoDB Manual for examples of how update works on the single field using Update Operators.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.